# select NodeSeq by it's id (IdSelector?)

Tags: scala, lift

How do I select a `NodeSeq` by it's id?

In lift, there are "`CssSelectors`" that allow you to do something like `"#myId" #> function`, and the `function` will receive only the desired NodeSeq as input.

But how do I use this fine "css selector" to select nodes, not only apply a function straight afterwards?

I know it can by done by searching all `"id"` attributes in NodeSeq, but isn't it more CPU-consuming than the Lift's version? Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ^^ selector (it ignores the right side of #>):

```scala
scala> import net.liftweb.util.Helpers._
import net.liftweb.util.Helpers._

scala> "#id ^^" #> "" apply <test><el id="id"/></test>
res0: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<el id="id"/>)
```

As for performance, obviously Lift has to iterate over the id attributes itself.

Comment: Thanks!! That's exactly what I was looking for!

About performance -- I'd still question that. For example, in most cases there is a finite and small amount of templates and selectors used by Lift. Both the templates (NodeSeq) and the selectors are immutable.

Why wouldn't Lift cache not only the NodeSeq, but applied selectors, too?

For example, if Lift's cached a template (.html) and sees a selector on this template, he may memoize some results.

Comment: I mean, AFAIK Lift doesn't do that, but he could. And maybe will in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could iterate through the `NodeSeq`.

```
val myNodeSeq = 
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li id="findme"></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

We could use Scala's XML parser to do something like:

```
myNodeSeq \\ "li" filter(_ \ "@id" contains scala.xml.Text("findme"))
```

Which would return: `NodeSeq(<li id="findme"></li>)`

I don't think the above is any more CPU intensive than Lift's version, but there is also no reason you couldn't use lift's CssSelector - it is broken out so don't even need the rest of the lift framework. So, something like:

```
("#findme" #> { ns =>
  //do something with ns - which is the NodeSeq that matches
}).apply(myNodeSeq)
```

You could also probably work something out using recursion and pattern matching.

If you are interested in how Lift actually does it's matching, you could take a look at the CSS selector stuff [here](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/2.4.1/core/util/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/util/BindHelpers.scala).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
About the first approach and the second -- well, I already mentioned them in the question. You really can iterate through NodeSeq and try to catch the template from the inside. The goal was to catch the NodeSeq as a variable, to be able to use it afterwards.

The link to the Lift's BindHelpers is useful anyway, thanks.)